# DateTime config php

Tags: php, sql-server

In my MSSQL Database Table the Column time is written in Dec 10 2019 10:02PM and the Data Type of the column is varchar(100)

> Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string 
>   (WedEurope/Berlin2019-12-11T12:23:53+01:00 11 2019 12:23PMDec)
>   at position 0 (W): The timezone could not be found in the database in

```
$_TimeColumn = "time"; // Column name that contains the Date/Time

$_DateFormat = "%h:%i:%s"; 

function _DateString($hi)
{
    global $_DateFormat;
    $now = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    $det = new DateTime(date($hi));

    return $now->diff($det)->format($_DateFormat);
}
```

Comment: How come you have made the date collum's data type a varchar and not a date/datetime?

Comment: The Database was a template

Comment: is the $_TimeColumn variable getting its value from the database?

Comment: yeah its like that

Comment: you do realise `$now = new DateTime();` is the same as `$now = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));`?

Comment: And you can say `$det = new DateTime($hi);`

Answer (score 0):

First I would change the datatype of the date column from a `varchar` to `datetime`.

Next create a select statement to get the information from the table while converting it to just the time value like this -

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($con, "
select 
    convert(varchar, DATETIME_COLUMN, 114) as DATETIME_COLUMN
from
    DATABASE_TABLE", array());

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
    $_TimeColumn = $row['DATETIME_COLLUMN'];
}
```

Once you echo out your $_TimeColumn it will only output the time in 24 hours with milliseconds. That should make it so it can be put into your code without your manual conversion and you'll be able to use that value correctly.